# App crash during edittext on click in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have created the on edittext addTextChangedListener.If i click the the edit text during onTextChanged.Two layouts will be hide and also asyntask will be called.At first time all these functionality will be working fine.If click the edit text on second time the app will crash.

> LOGCAT:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.abservetech.jobstar, PID: 24942
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a ColorStateList (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x101009b a=1}
at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2330)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:343)
at android.text.style.TextAppearanceSpan.<init>(TextAppearanceSpan.java:65)
at android.text.style.TextAppearanceSpan.<init>(TextAppearanceSpan.java:45)
at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow$SuggestionInfo.<init>(Editor.java:2431)
at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow$SuggestionInfo.<init>(Editor.java:2426)
at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:2414)
at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2237)
at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2372)
at android.widget.Editor.showSuggestions(Editor.java:1727)
at android.widget.Editor$1.run(Editor.java:1629)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:970)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

> CODE:

```
searchkey.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        hidelayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        searchlist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});

searchkey.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        headline = s.toString();
        new searchkillskill().execute(headline);
        hidelayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        searchlist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

xml coding:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.abservetech.jobstar.WorkExperience">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText

                android:id="@+id/searchkey"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:hint="@string/Keyskills_Designations"



                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_cnfpassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#aaaaaa" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/second_view_cnfpassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#FF9800"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </FrameLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/hidelayout">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout5"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayout5"
                android:text="@string/Location"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/hslocation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"

                />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/autocompletsearch"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey"

                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cancel"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView57"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout5"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayout5"
                        android:text="@string/Experience"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/hsexperience"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_weight=".5" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout5"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout5"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView59"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout5"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayout5"
                        android:text="@string/salary"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/hssalary"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight=".5" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/searchjobs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView49"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="@string/SearchJobs"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/homesearchlist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: https://github.com/ACRA/acra/issues/363 Maybe this an help you

Comment: your color is not recognize so better way is create new file and copy paste your code there and rebuild it should work.

Comment: Because when you click on your edittext your hide layout visibility is gone and when you type then again you use code to hide layout to visibility gone again. May be you can remove hide layout and searchlist visibility code from onTextChanged or create a condition to check before setVisibility in onTextChanged :)

Comment: i have posted my xml coding @vrundpurohit

Answer (score 0):

This Error occurs most of the time because of theme is not configured properly, try using default theme for application and then run application as you are doing now. It may work for you.